# Unable to deploy app to GAE - unable to assign value '<unknown>' to attribute 'url'

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth

I am currently using the book "Programming for Google Glass" by Eric Redmond to learn how to create apps for Google Glass.  There is a section where the author presents code for using Google's OAuth to be able to authorize the app. I am new to OAuth and, even though given the code, I am having a problem deploying my app (prior to adding the OAuth code, the app could deploy to GAE, but you couldn't use it on Glass).

The error I get says:

```
Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: 
https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=glassebooktest&version=1&
400 Bad Request
Error when loading application configuration:
Unable to assign value '<unknown>' to attribute 'url':
Value u'\\\u200b.*\\\u200b' for ??? could not be converted to type str.


See the deployment console for more details
Unable to update app: Error posting to URL:     
https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=glassebooktest&version=1&
400 Bad Request
Error when loading application configuration:
Unable to assign value '<unknown>' to attribute 'url':
Value u'\\\u200b.*\\\u200b' for ??? could not be converted to type str.
```

I figured the easiest way to view the code is from the repo for the book's code:
https://github.com/coderoshi/glassmirror/tree/master/chapter-3/src/test/book/glass

It seems it's trying to assign a value to the variable 'url' but not able to.  The only place I've noticed a variable called 'url' is in the method 'fullurl' from the file in the 'auth' directory called 'AuthUtils.java'

```
public static String fullUrl( HttpServletRequest req, String rawPath )
{
    GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl( new String(req.getRequestURL()) );
    url.setRawPath( rawPath );
    return url.build();
}
```

Unfortunately, the book does not explain this section and I'm having a hard time troubleshooting.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I do not have a app.yaml file and my appengine-web.xml fil is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>glassebooktest</application>
  <version>1</version>

  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

  <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>

</appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: I added the contents of the appengine-web.xml file.  I also do not have a app.yaml file (I was told it would be in the WEB-INF folder).

Answer (score 0):

Check the url handler in your app.yaml or appengine-web.xml.  My guess is that you copied/pasted the handler, and it's picking up an illegal character.  Try typing it in as `/.*`

`u'\\\u200b.*\\\u200b'` corresponds to `\\.*\\` with illegal non-spaces.